# Can you Hoverslam without going vertical?

Tags: spacex, design-alternative

Problem of the day, that pesky Starship Hoverslam.

Imagining a crazy (childish) contest to see who could flip at the lowest altitude and brake to 0 rate of descent and land, it was (hilariously) imagined one could "cheat" by braking in the horizontal with "side rockets" then flipping and landing.

Then, it was realized, **could just the engines be gimballed 90 degrees** for a horizontal landing.  Yes, another would be needed in front.

Conceptually, the design might be a bit like the Harrier, *but could control pitch just like a Chinook helicopter*, and enable one to make the aerodynamic fins smaller.

Could this be practical?

Comment: What exactly do you want to gain by that, increasing the gimbal range tenfold, installing another set of landing gear and duplicating all the plumbing and pumping for a second engine at the top?

Comment: Easier to disembark, for starters.  Larger, more stable landing base.  Better control in descent.  **Much** wider available CG range.

Comment: They're duplicating the plumbing anyways, aren't they.  A nose Merlin would weigh around than 630 kg.

Comment: They are not duplicating any plumbing, the only added plumbing in the current approach is the downcomers from the header tanks. A nose Merlin would require an entire additional fuel tank for the RP-1, and a single Merlin would lack redundancy. And descending horizontally with rockets at nose and tail would be far, far more difficult to control and require major increases in structural mass.

Comment: The concept is not crazy, but trying to shoehorn it into the StarShip design is. Different paths of optimization would be required, and an utter redo of structural and plumbing design.

Comment: @PcMan  Which they shouldn't be afraid of doing at this point.  The current Starship is long and graceful (if you like SLBMs) but could be made *shorter and wider* to facilitate tail first landings in other worlds (like the Apollo LEM).  Note this need not affect the parameters of the booster.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni umm, no? If you make the Starship shorter and wider, you *greatly* exacerbate the structural problems of making it capable of landing "on its side". The problem is *already* that the reinforcement needed to make a 9m-wide tube rigid enough and resilient enough without hugely increasing its mass. Double its diameter, and the problem becomes double^3 = 8 times as hard to solve... Thin stainless steel plating is *very* strong in its length, and ridiculously weak against transverse forces(denting & buckling)

Comment: @PcMan Oh, come on.  Make it wider and land on the tail (as originally planned).  The "Starship" design may soon radiate into Earth, Moon, and Mars versions rather than the oft ill fated "jack of all trades, king of none" approach.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni This question pertains to the OP's suggestion of landing the StarShip on its side. You should respect the OP's question, why I believe he may even be a relative of yours. He has the same name, anyways. It's bad to disrespect a relative by trying to derail his question like that!

Comment: @PcMan no, one and the same, but evolving.

Comment: You are talking about developing a completely new vehicle. This would be hugely more expensive up-front, it would take far more time, and the lack of design commonality would also make it more expensive to operate and largely eliminate the safety and reliability benefits to be gained from Starship's high flight rate. Why would they do this? There's no reason to expect the planned relatively minor modifications to not do the job just fine.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff the same things were said about the Space Shuttle years ago.  I hear your points,  but cannot commit to the design this early on.  Reminds me a bit of James Michener describing how locomotives were developed.  Some by scale-up and some by full scale iterations.  But, by determination, they both succeeded.

Comment: ...no, nobody said it about the Space Shuttle. It wouldn't even make sense to do so, as the base design was useless for anything other than a surface-LEO shuttle. And SpaceX doesn't need you to "commit" to their design. It's *their* design, and your various complaints about it only show that you don't understand it or its justifications. Despite, as I've pointed out, the information being widely available if you'd just do some minimal research rather than digging in on misguided ideas like adding parachutes or landing the thing sideways.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I'm sorry I have to answer.  "Benefits gained from ... high flight rate" was the Shuttle's main selling point, and I must point out your (amirable but rigid) clinging to one design has been shown to be long term disastrous many times.  Early on, open minds pay dividends.  As SpaceX has a lead even Secretariat could only dream of, they have room to maneuver to an even better outcome.

Comment: I'm not the one obsessing over approaches that were shown long, long ago to be inadequate, refusing to acknowledge the issues with my favored ideas, and rejecting an approach apparently based on nothing but my feelings about it. That's **you**.

Comment: Testing and development includes *all* approaches, and usually (when done properly), results in an *optimal **applications driven** solution*.  The eventual Martian Starship, with a wider base (more drag, safer landing, easier disembark) *may* be able to come in without a flip.  But, for research purposes, continued development of the "flip" maneuver may be of value.  Let's see if SN 10 can do it better.

Answer (score 20):

Unlikely to be plausible. During belly flop descent the forces placed on the horizontal Starship are distributed over the windward side very evenly. The cylinder walls represent the majority of the frontal area and the flaps are fluttered back taking less than their full potential drag - and their mounts are still naturally broad and spread the additional force over the skin.

During flip the aft drag will reduce as the aft flaps feather, meaning off-axis force on the aft drops. The nose flaps do flare for higher drag, but they are the smallest of the flaps and their impulse will rapidly drop off as the ship rotates and the area they present to the wind reduces. The major impulse for the flip is provided by the engines through the thrust puck and typical rocket structures.

When the large deceleration for landing occurs after the flip, the engine thrust is aligned with the tank walls, distributed there by the thrust puck - again as during ascent.

Applying the thrust forces perpendicular to the tank walls would overwhelm the thin tank structure. Applying the necessary structural reinforcements to support the mass horizontally at small points would greatly increase the dry mass, reducing payload.

Comment: Valid answer.  I submit a landing Starship would have considerably less mass, there for fewer stresses.  Yes, it would have to be more robust, but with no existing $/kg to Mars parameters, a stronger build might have additional safety benefits.

Comment: While Mars is indisputably the major goal of everything SpaceX, none of their engineering decisions can be made in a vacuum (in fact, I'd argue their ability to consider a multitude of outside factors is another major facet of what makes them special). Any cheap cargo to and from Mars is a win, but a system that carries more in less flights is better. And a system that's cheap to fly even by LEO standards will make Mars even more economical. Plus make more profits available to Mars operations

Comment: You're not adding safety margins, you're adding structure to keep it from snapping in half under stresses unlike those it encounters at any other point in its flight. That's mass that could instead be devoted to actually improving safety margins if necessary, and which could otherwise be used for useful payload.

Comment: Beg to differ there. The flop descent puts *aerodynamic* stresses at the exact same points the landing rockets would.  And the ancient Greeks figured out how to prevent their ships from "snapping in half" while being light enough to float.

Comment: The flop descent does no such thing, the flaps support only a fraction of the vehicle's weight. And Starship is not a boat.

Comment: Consider frontal area to the wind during flop. The bulk of it is the windward side of the cylinder of Starship. The flaps on the edges of the cylinder are fluttered back to take less than their full potential drag, and are smaller than the body. Then flip reduces drag at the aft, reducing off-axis forces on the structure. It flares the nose slightly which would increase off-axis force there, but the nose flaps are the smallest. Then a thrust off-axis but through the thrust puck applies hard flight-similar force. The flip-flop needs less off-axis reinforcement than horizontal landing.

Comment: @Saiboogu  would you be interested if it was found you could land horizontally on the moon with 8-10 **Kestrels**.  We could also do a little distribution of thrust to ease stress a bit.

Comment: The Kestrel has been out of production for about a decade. It also was an upper stage engine designed with no need for fast or accurate throttle adjustments, and your proposed landing approach would be reliant on throttling for control, while also making the vehicle much more sensitive to throttling error. And it used the wrong fuel. And it wasn't reusable.

Comment: I'd call this a solution in search of a problem. Vertical landing has a mountain of perks to it, and is pretty key to their operational plans and the design of the vehicle. Horizontal landing adds little positive, and has a mountain of hangups and issues associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to bring along more rocket engines.  If the thrust axis does not go through the center of mass of the craft the craft will rotate and landing while rotating is a crash.  The Starship has all it's engines at the rear--incapable of pointing through the center of mass unless they're pointed virtually straight down.